# +1 to value column for duplicate entries in a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a PHP script search script that logs every query made in a MySQL database. Currently, if the same terms are searched more than once, a duplicate of the query will be added to the database. How can I make it so when a term is already in the database +1 is added to a column titled value?

My PHP code is:

```
<?php

$database=mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
mysql_select_db("database",$database);

$query=$_GET['q'];

logQuery($query);
function logQuery($query){
$query="insert into queries (query) values ('$query')";
mysql_query($query);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, create a unique index on the `query` field using:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX query_idx ON queries (query)
```

Then, alter your `INSERT` query to update the `value` field when a duplicate `query` is found (it will hit the `query_idx` index):

```
INSERT INTO queries (query) VALUES ('$query')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = value + 1
```

Take a look at the documentation for [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) for more details about this.

Also, don't forget to use `mysql_real_escape_string($query)` instead of simply using `$query`, because if you don't escape the string and the `$query` variable contains, for example, `'` characters, it will corrupt your `INSERT` query.

Answer (score 0):

You could do an INSERT On Duplicate aand add a coloumn called value to queries. Just make sure you set the query column as a unique index

on your SQL:

```
<?php

$database=mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
mysql_select_db("database",$database);

$query=$_GET['q'];

logQuery($query);
function logQuery($query){
$query="insert into queries (query) values ('$query')
 on duplicate key update value=value+1;
";
mysql_query($query);
}
?>
```